# Searching words starting with a specific letter on google?

Tags: google-search, google

I want to search for words starting with a specific letter in the same order. Is there any operator in google-dorks through which I can apply wild operations on letters instead of words?

Example: Basic query for wild operations on words is `Super * Car`

I want to do the same with letters (it would be something like this `Super B* Car`)

It would be great if there's a solution to quickly do that in some way. Otherwise, I may have to go for python script.

Thank You